# IE11 display:flex is giving me grief. Why is it not displaying correctly?

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11

I recently realized that `display: flex` is supported, but full of bugs in IE11. Now I cannot make my simple grid based menu work.

I have a set of buttons, which adjusts their size based on window size. They use flexbox and a absolute positioning approach, with top, bottom, left and right set to 0.

However, this does not display correctly in IE11, which I need to support. I ahve tried to find out why, but due to IE's extremely inferiour debugging tool, I have not been able to. I have tried to go through all of the known bugs and issues, stated [here.](http://caniuse.com/#search=display%3A%20flex)However, none of them apply to me. I have min-width set, but not min-height. I have also tried to see if the same bug could be applied for the horizontal axis, as the verticalm but it made no difference, trying to solve it by setting a width, along with min-, and max-width. The happy news is that IE finally works with JSFiddle now, so I am easily able to reproduce the error.

How can I make the elements display as the do in Chrome?

https://jsfiddle.net/7oa3dzvk/

HTML:

```
<body><div class="wrapper"><div class="middle"><div class="centering-container"><div class="container"><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12"><div class="container"><div class="row padding-top">
                                    <div class=" col-xs-6">
                                        <div class="square-box pull-right">
                                            <div class="auto-height-ratio-content E-envi" onclick="listTestBanksByEnvironment('E')">E</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-6 ">
                                        <div class="square-box">
                                            <div class="auto-height-ratio-content F-envi" onclick="listTestBanksByEnvironment('F')">
                                                <div class="center-text ">F</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div></div></div></div></div></div></div></div></body>
```

CSS: (most relevant close to the bottom, as much of it is bootstrap generated, but still needed for the complete example)

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
* {
    font-family: Lato;
}
* {
    outline: none;
}
body {
    margin: 0;
}
html {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
::after, ::before {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
.padding-top {
    padding-top: 30px;
}
.container {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.container {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
    background: #FAFAFA;
    padding: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after, .btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::before, .btn-toolbar::after, .btn-toolbar::before, .clearfix::after, .clearfix::before, .container-fluid::after, .container-fluid::before, .container::after, .container::before, .dl-horizontal dd::after, .dl-horizontal dd::before, .form-horizontal .form-group::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::before, .modal-footer::after, .modal-footer::before, .nav::after, .nav::before, .navbar-collapse::after, .navbar-collapse::before, .navbar-header::after, .navbar-header::before, .navbar::after, .navbar::before, .pager::after, .pager::before, .panel-body::after, .panel-body::before, .row::after, .row::before {
    display: table;
    content: " ";
}
.btn-group-vertical > .btn-group::after, .btn-toolbar::after, .clearfix::after, .container-fluid::after, .container::after, .dl-horizontal dd::after, .form-horizontal .form-group::after, .modal-footer::after, .nav::after, .navbar-collapse::after, .navbar-header::after, .navbar::after, .pager::after, .panel-body::after, .row::after {
    clear: both;
}
.container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
.container {
    width: 750px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:992px) */
.container {
    width: 970px;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:1200px) */
.container {
    width: 1170px;
}
.col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
.col-xs-1, .col-xs-10, .col-xs-11, .col-xs-12, .col-xs-2, .col-xs-3, .col-xs-4, .col-xs-5, .col-xs-6, .col-xs-7, .col-xs-8, .col-xs-9 {
    float: left;
}
.col-xs-12 {
    width: 100%;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
.col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9 {
    float: left;
}
/* @media all and (min-width:768px) */
.col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.middle {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 65px;
    position: relative;
}
.wrapper {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
body {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.4285;
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
}
html {
    font-size: 10px;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.col-xs-6 {
    width: 50%;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.square-box {
    position: relative;
    min-width: 70px;
    max-width: 150px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 75px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}
.square-box::before {
    content: "";
    padding-top: 100%;
}
.F-envi {
    background-color: #99bfc2;
    color: #003946;
}
.E-envi {
    background-color: #d1c99d;
    color: #003946;
}
.auto-height-ratio-content {
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefixes for IE is not added in css. [autoprefixer.github.io/](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) - will help to add proper prefixes.

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
```

Please check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/7oa3dzvk/3/

Also `position:absolute;` is not working with flex. So used `flex-grow` to stretch the content.

Comment: Although this is not completely perfect, it works :). IE won't display equal width and height for each menu element, but at least it will display them in a satisfactory way, and with minimal change to the code. Welll done, sir. And thanks.

Answer (score 0):

IE 11 partially supports Flexbox, you may use [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) for checking which properties are supported, also read the following link on how to normalize flexbox through different browsers.
http://philipwalton.com/articles/normalizing-cross-browser-flexbox-bugs/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.